# Flutter Can't Find javaHome

Tags: java, flutter, path

So I'm trying flutter and I'm having a problem with running the starter app on my emulator. I first installed flutter alongside the electric eel version of android studio, which had problems with the java path. I fixed the problem by just copying the jdk folder contents to the jre folder. and because of "LIFE" I left flutter for about a month or so. today I decided to start it over but when I try to launch the starter app that flutter creates on the emulator via vscode, I get the following error:

```
PS E:\projects\first_app> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,010ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and i have no idea why it thinks that the jdk path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\bin\java.exe` while my android studio is installed in the `Z:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`

copying the contents of the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19` folder into the `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2\` folder fixes the issue and the app launches but this removes my jre which a lot of apps need.

I tried setting some environment paths to fix the issue but they did nothing

[image]

and below is the PATH variables:

[image]

EDIT: since taking these screenshots I've also tried setting a `javaHome` variable alongside the `JAVA_HOME` variable. that didn't fix the issue either. also I've set both of the to have the `\bin` folder too. no help.

**EDIT 2: so... for some reason uninstalling all java installations on my pc with revo fixed the problem. I reinstalled java v8 and the problem didn't occur again, so I guess problem fixed?! I'm closing the thread and posting this in case anyone else found themselves here**

Comment: can you restart after setting env varidables

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JAVA_HOME` without `%`, It will look like

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| JAVA_HOME | C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19 |

[image]

And restart your computer if needed.

Comment: the variable itself is without the `%`. so unfortunately this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I am using jdk 11, you can give a try, also make sure to match other folders include bin inside bin inside it